# Frequent sites on SharePoint Online Home Page

Tags: spfx, office-365-developer, microsoft-graph, pnp-js-core, office-dev-pnp

Is there a way I can have "Frequent sites" on my website? Is this a webpart or SpFx component that I can add to any of my existing site?

I would like below into my own site page.

[image]

Digging bit more I found below API calls which receive data for SharePoint Home Page.

**Featured links :** https://eastus23-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/orglinks?start=0&count=11

**Following sites :** https://eastus23-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/followed?mostRecentFirst=true&start=0&count=100&fillSiteData=true&fillSiteCount=10

**Frequent sites :** https://eastus23-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/feed?start=0&count=13&acronyms=true

**Recent Sites :** https://eastus23-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/recent?start=0&count=6&acronyms=true

**Suggested Sites :** https://eastus23-sphomep.svc.ms/api/v1/sites/suggested?start=0&count=21&acronyms=true

Does anyone aware of how these API can be consumed?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this might answer your question

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-links-list-on-sharepoint-home-page?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fchange-the-links-list-on-the-sharepoint-home-page-aa93f89b-ffce-4edb-aa89-22b16d6915a7

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but this does not say anything about "Frequent sites" that we see on SharePoint Home Page.

Comment: As the name implies, it shows the recent sites you have visited. It is very useful in the context of daily work and collaboration. Say, you are part of a particular department and are a member of the few project team sites. As the old projects end and new ones begin, the recent tab will always adjust accordingly and automatically and will always show you the recent sites you have visited. The analogy of this is Recent Documents section in Word or Excel that shows you the files you worked on recently.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but what I am interested in is to add "Frequent sites" into my own page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, it shows the recent sites you have visited. It is very useful in the context of daily work and collaboration. Say, you are part of a particular department and are a member of the few project team sites. As the old projects end and new ones begin, the recent tab will always adjust accordingly and automatically and will always show you the recent sites you have visited. The analogy of this is Recent Documents section in Word or Excel that shows you the files you worked on recently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can fetch the results from the above call. But the domain part i.e eastus will be same or different for you it is actually the region information like US or Europe then you need to hit this service with appropriate headers you will get the result. You can even check the exact url in the network tab of developer tool.